# Docker: Can different containers use different base Images?

Tags: docker

I want to build my application infrastructure from the following containers:

- mongoDb
- Mysql
- MariaDb
- My application

Can I just use for DBs containers from docker Hub even if they use different base images, or I should build my infrastructure on the same base image. I found examples for both options. What is the best practice?

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30759829/776208) can give you some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's absolutely no difference between these two option except you're gonna waste some of your time to build something that is already built!

If you want an especial customization you can do it in a pre-built image and create a new image for your own!

Comment: Adding to that: It is one of the main advantages of using docker that an image provides you with a service and you _really_ do not have to care about how this service is provided. adding `docker-compose` to the mix makes deploying applications a charm